# How to search for a word and add a suffix to the next occurrence of the word?

Tags: c, parsing, awk, sed

I have a file foo.h
The file has some macros and they are repeating twice. I want to add a suffix '_repeat' to the next occurrence.
There are many such repetitions in the file. I want to write a generic script to add suffix to the second occurence.

For eg.

```
/* Info: VARIABLE */

#define VARIABLE 02
```

I want it to look like,

```
/* Info: VARIABLE */

#define VARIABLE_repeat 02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/VARIABLE/{:a;N;/(VARIABLE).*\1/!ba;s//&_repeat/}' file
```

Gather up lines on encountering the required string until a second occurence is matched then append a suffix.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '($1=="#define"){a[$2]++}(a[$2]==2){$2=$2 "_repeat"}1' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no guarantees of robustness, but you could start with:

```
awk '$1 == "#define" && a[$2]++{ $2=$2 "_repeat" a[$2]} 1' foo.h
```

this will handle multiple repetitions, appending "_repeat2", "_repeat3", etc. to duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl version that - to me at least - seems much easier to understand:

```
perl -p -e 's/(#define\s+)(\w+)/"$1$2".(++$w{$2} > 1 ? "_repeated" : "")/e' < foo.h
```

or here's another version:

```
perl -p -e 's/(#define\s+)(\w+)/$x='_repeated' if ++$w{$2} > 1; "$1$2$x"/e' < foo.h
```